# How to add an 'escape button' to a website in HTML?

Tags: html, button

I'm trying to add an "escape button" to a Domestic Abuse help site for an HTML project. I have the button, an image, and it works, but the problem is that you can click outside of the image and it triggers the button. I'm trying to find a way to contain the button activation to inside the picture, not outside of it.

```
<p id="escape" onclick="myFunction()">
<img src="quickescape.png">
</p>

<script>
        function myFunction() {
            // Get away right now
            window.open("http://weather.com", "_newtab");
            // Replace current site with another benign site
            window.location.replace('http://google.com');
        }
        </script>
```

Here's a demo of what I'm encountering if it wasn't clear: https://imgur.com/a/5QepBU1

Do I need to use a map id? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: but your code works well with tag `p`. i checked it myself. I can click on any area of the picture and the js code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myFunction is activated when clicking where p tag is. If p tag has space then onClick event will be in space too. Giving myFunction event to img tag will not accept activating function on empty space.

```html
<p id="escape" >
<img src="quickescape.png" onclick="myFunction()">
</p>

<script>
        function myFunction() {
            // Get away right now
            window.open("http://weather.com", "_newtab");
            // Replace current site with another benign site
            window.location.replace('http://google.com');
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don’t wrap it in a ‘p’ tag (that is a block level element).  Wrap it in an inline element, like an ‘a’ or ‘span’.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very good idea. If I were you, I would use this example below so that the website's last url won't show up in the history section.

```js
function quickEscape() {
  window.location.replace('https://www.example.com')
}
```

```css
button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url('https://www.sciencemag.org/sites/default/files/styles/article_main_large/public/butterfly_16x9_0.jpg?itok=jZ3DYvGK');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: pink;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  -webkit-text-stroke: white 1px;
  outline: none;
  border: pink solid 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='quickEscape()'>Quick Escape</button>
```